# Getting Error when running app

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-gallery

Hello when the app is running everything works fine, but when i try to click save i get an error. At first it had and error with the external storage permission. I fixed that but now I'm getting the error below.

Can someone look at my code and see if you can see what I'm missing?

It says `NullPointerException` but the line that it is pointing to has no `null` points in the code.

**Code:**

```
package com.androidbook.pettracker3;

import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FilterQueryProvider;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

import com.androidbook.pettracker3.PetTrackerDatabase.PetType;
import com.androidbook.pettracker3.PetTrackerDatabase.Pets;

public class PetTrackerEntryActivity extends PetTrackerActivity implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
private static final int GALLERY_CURSOR_LOADER_ID = 0x1001;
private static final String GALLERY_CURSOR_URI_ARG =     "GALLERY_CURSOR_URI_ARG";
protected Cursor mCursorAutoComplete;
protected Cursor mThumbnailImagesCursor;

private Gallery imagePickerGallery;
private ImageUriAdapter mGalleryAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // use this to note how the setImageURI method is bad
    /*StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectAll().penaltyFlashScreen().penaltyLog().build());

 */
    setContentView(R.layout.petentry);

    // Fill our Gallery from pictures available on the SD Card
    setGalleryAdapter();

    // Fill AutoComplete word list from database
    fillAutoComplete();

    imagePickerGallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.GalleryOfPics);

    // Handle Save Button
    final Button savePet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSave);
    savePet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final EditText petName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
            final EditText petType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextSpecies);
            long imageId = PetRecord.INVALID_PET_IMAGE_ID;

            ImageView selectedImageView = (ImageView) imagePickerGallery
                    .getSelectedView();

            Uri imageUri = (Uri) selectedImageView.getTag();
            String imageUriString = imageUri.toString();

            String strPetType = petType.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
            String strPetName = petName.getText().toString();
            PetRecord newRecord = new PetRecord(strPetName, strPetType,
                    imageUriString, imageId, PetRecord.INVALID_PET_ID);
            addPetRecord(newRecord);

            // reset form
            petName.setText(null);
            petType.setText(null);
        }
    });

    // Handle Go to List button
    final Button gotoList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonShowPets);
    gotoList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Go to other activity that displays pet list
            Intent intent = new Intent(PetTrackerEntryActivity.this,
                    PetTrackerListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

//
private void setGalleryAdapter() {

    // The base URI for SD Card content
    Uri thumbnailUri = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    mGalleryAdapter = new ImageUriAdapter(this, null, false, thumbnailUri);

    // Assign the adapter to our Gallery to display the images
    final Gallery pictureGal = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.GalleryOfPics);
    pictureGal.setAdapter(mGalleryAdapter);

    // use a loader to get the cursor and assign it to this adapter
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(GALLERY_CURSOR_URI_ARG, thumbnailUri.toString());
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(GALLERY_CURSOR_LOADER_ID, args, this);
}

private void fillAutoComplete() {
    mCursorAutoComplete = mDB.query(PetType.PETTYPE_TABLE_NAME,
            new String[] { PetType.PET_TYPE_NAME, PetType._ID }, null,
            null, null, null, PetType.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

    startManagingCursor(mCursorAutoComplete);

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
            mCursorAutoComplete, new String[] { PetType.PET_TYPE_NAME },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

    // I just want the text splatted into the edittext, not the textview
    // object
    // so I implemented a CursorToStringConverter and a FilterQueryProvider
    // CursorToStringConverter - controls what "value" is returned when an
    // AutoText option is chosen
    // in this case, the text itself, not the id to the text
    // FilterQueryProvider - interface to get control over the filtering
    // process, which we implement a custom matching function
    adapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new MyCursorToStringConverter());
    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new MyFilterQueryProvider());

    AutoCompleteTextView text = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.EditTextSpecies);
    text.setAdapter(adapter);

}

// This controls what column to place in the edittext when selected. The
// default textview.tostring, not helpful
class MyCursorToStringConverter implements
        SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter {

    public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
        return cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(PetType.PET_TYPE_NAME));
    }
}

// Our custom filter finds all substring matches, not just the beginning of
// the string, just for kicks
// There's a bit of a workaround here, since this function does not handle
// Cursor refreshing appropriately
class MyFilterQueryProvider implements FilterQueryProvider {

    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

        if ((constraint != null) && (mCursorAutoComplete != null)) {
            String strWhere = PetType.PET_TYPE_NAME + " LIKE ?";

            stopManagingCursor(mCursorAutoComplete);
            mCursorAutoComplete = mDB
                    .query(PetType.PETTYPE_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
                            PetType.PET_TYPE_NAME, PetType._ID }, strWhere,
                            new String[] { "%" + constraint.toString()
                                    + "%" }, null, null,
                            PetType.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
            startManagingCursor(mCursorAutoComplete);
        }

        return mCursorAutoComplete;
    }
}

// Add appropriate records to the database (Pet and Pet_Type)
private void addPetRecord(PetRecord newRecord) {

    // Save new records, since we're saving multiple records, let's do a
    // transaction so it's all or nothing
    mDB.beginTransaction();
    try {

        // check if species type exists already
        long rowPetTypeId = 0;

        // SQL Query -> "select * from table_pettype where
        // PetType.pettype_name='string'
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.setTables(PetType.PETTYPE_TABLE_NAME);
        queryBuilder.appendWhere(PetType.PET_TYPE_NAME + "='"
                + newRecord.getPetType() + "'");

        // run the query since it's all ready to go
        Cursor c = queryBuilder.query(mDB, null, null, null, null, null,
                null);

        if (c.getCount() == 0) {
            // add the new type to our list
            ContentValues typeRecordToAdd = new ContentValues();
            typeRecordToAdd.put(PetType.PET_TYPE_NAME,
                    newRecord.getPetType());
            rowPetTypeId = mDB.insert(PetType.PETTYPE_TABLE_NAME,
                    PetType.PET_TYPE_NAME, typeRecordToAdd);

        } else {
            // Type already exists, grab the row id to refer to below
            c.moveToFirst();
            rowPetTypeId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(PetType._ID));
        }

        c.close();

        // Always insert new pet records, even if the names clash
        ContentValues petRecordToAdd = new ContentValues();
        petRecordToAdd.put(Pets.PET_NAME, newRecord.getPetName());
        petRecordToAdd.put(Pets.PET_TYPE_ID, rowPetTypeId);
        petRecordToAdd.put(Pets.PET_IMAGE_URI,
                newRecord.getPetImageUriPath());
        petRecordToAdd.put(Pets.PET_IMAGE_ID, newRecord.getPetImageId());
        mDB.insert(Pets.PETS_TABLE_NAME, Pets.PET_NAME, petRecordToAdd);

        mDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        mDB.endTransaction();
    }
}

public class ImageUriAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private int colIndexMediaId;
    private final Uri baseUri;
    private final int mGalleryItemBackground;

    public ImageUriAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery,
            Uri baseUri) {
        super(context, c, autoRequery);
        if (c != null) {
            colIndexMediaId = c
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
        }
        this.baseUri = baseUri;

        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.default_gallery);
        mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
        R.styleable.default_gallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        long id = cursor.getLong(colIndexMediaId);

        // TODO: this should be done on a background thread; it blocks
        Uri imageUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri, String.valueOf(id));
        ((ImageView) view).setImageURI(imageUri);
        view.setTag(imageUri);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        long id = cursor.getLong(colIndexMediaId);

        // TODO: this should be done on a background thread; it blocks
        Uri imageUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri, String.valueOf(id));
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);

        // Constrain the images so they all look the same size/ratio
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        imageView.setTag(imageUri);

        imageView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
        if (newCursor != null) {
            colIndexMediaId = newCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
        }
        return super.swapCursor(newCursor);
    }
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    switch (id) {
    case GALLERY_CURSOR_LOADER_ID:
        // An array specifying which columns to return.
        String[] projection = new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };

        // The base URI for SD Card content
        Uri thumbnailUri = Uri
                .parse(args.getString(GALLERY_CURSOR_URI_ARG));

        // thumbnails of all external images in the media store
        // Best way to retrieve a cursor; performs operation on a background
        // thread
        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, thumbnailUri,
                projection, null, null,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER
                        //+ " limit 50"
                        );
        return loader;
    }

    return null;

}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    switch (cursorLoader.getId()) {
    case GALLERY_CURSOR_LOADER_ID:
        mGalleryAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
    switch (cursorLoader.getId()) {
    case GALLERY_CURSOR_LOADER_ID:
        mGalleryAdapter.swapCursor(null);
        break;
    }
}
```

**Error message**

```
D/dalvikvm: Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
04-07 15:25:41.172 2212-2212/? E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such     file or directory (2)
04-07 15:25:41.172 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 W/ActivityThread:     Application com.androidbook.pettracker3 is waiting for the debugger on port    8100...
04-07 15:25:41.182 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
04-07 15:25:41.842 2212-2219/com.androidbook.pettracker3 I/dalvikvm: Debugger is active
04-07 15:25:42.012 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 I/System.out: Debugger has connected
04-07 15:25:42.012 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
04-07 15:25:42.212 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
04-07 15:25:42.422 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
04-07 15:25:42.632 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
04-07 15:25:42.842 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
04-07 15:25:43.052 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
04-07 15:25:43.262 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
04-07 15:25:43.472 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
04-07 15:25:43.682 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
04-07 15:25:43.892 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 I/System.out: debugger has settled (1352)
04-07 15:25:43.922 2212-2217/com.androidbook.pettracker3 D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 131K, 7% free 2675K/2864K, paused 7ms+0ms, total 9ms
04-07 15:25:43.942 2212-2217/com.androidbook.pettracker3 D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 117K, 9% free 2958K/3216K, paused 3ms+0ms, total 5ms
04-07 15:25:43.972 2212-2217/com.androidbook.pettracker3 D/dalvikvm:  GC_CONCURRENT freed 129K, 8% free 3228K/3480K, paused 9ms+1ms, total 12ms
04-07 15:25:44.041 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
04-07 15:25:44.041 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
04-07 15:25:44.041 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
04-07 15:25:44.092 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-07 15:25:44.092 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
04-07 15:26:22.622 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-07 15:26:22.622 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2d17908)
04-07 15:26:22.622 2212-2212/com.androidbook.pettracker3 E/AndroidRuntime:
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException
   at  com.androidbook.pettracker3.PetTrackerEntryActivity$1.onClick(PetTrackerEntryAct ivity.java:70)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   04-07 15:26:27.422 2212-2212/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2212 SIG: 9
```

petentry.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
   <TextView
      style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/enter_data"
      android:textColor="#0f0" />
   <TableLayout
      android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:shrinkColumns="*"
      android:stretchColumns="1" >
      <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pet Name:" >
        </TextView>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapWords" >
        </EditText>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pet Species:" >
        </TextView>
        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/EditTextSpecies"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </AutoCompleteTextView>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Choose Pet Picture:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/GalleryOfPics"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2" >
        </Gallery>
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonSave"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/save" >
  </Button>
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonShowPets"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show All Pets"
    android:textColor="#0f0" >
  </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: One of your buttons is null. Check that `petentry.xml` contains the all the id's that you are trying to find

Comment: added petentry.xml code.

Comment: My bad, not one of the buttons. `selectedImageView` is null. Just read the error. It says it's on line 70.

Comment: I did check it but there is no null notation in that method. I'm just leaning and i don't understand how that can be null. Ty for the help so far by the way.

Comment: `getSelectedView()` will return null if nothing is selected. Says it in the Android documentation.

Comment: Ok let me see if i go this the line the error is     'Uri imageUri = (Uri) selectedImageView.getTag();'. So to change it from null you need to put something in the .getTag brackets, right?

Comment: `getTag()` takes no paramaters. Your error points to that line because `getTag()` cannot be called on the `selectedImageView` variable because it is null, thus the error. It is null because the `getSelectedView()` method that you called on your Gallery variable returned null for the reason I mentioned above

Comment: kk let me fiddle around with it ty very much!!!

Comment: Ok i think i may have an idea. I think the problem is the fact that is't trying to use android.widget.gallery but is deprecated, this code was written with old API's. i think i need to change the code to use viewPager but have know idea how to do that.